# WPF: RibbonGalleryCategory and IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

I have Ribbon menu from RibbonControlsLibrary. 
I have RibbonGalleryCategory:

```
<RibbonGalleryCategory Header="Recent Documents" 
                       ItemsSource="{Binding RecentDocuments}">
...
</RibbonGalleryCategory>
```

How can I synchronize selected item with MVVM? 
How can I bind selected item on my ICommand?
`RibbonGalleryCategory.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Your RibbonGalleryCategory needs to be part of a RibbonGallery. You set the selected item on that.

```
<RibbonGallery SelectedItem="RecentDocument">
    <RibbonGalleryCategory Header="Recent Documents"
                           ItemsSource="{Binding RecentDocuments}">
    ...
    </RibbonGalleryCategory>
</RibbonGallery>
```